# Cheat Engine Memory Address of Program Assembly Changing

Tags: python, c++, memory, memory-management, process

I have a program that I have written myself in Python using PyGame and I would like to be able to create a C++ program to edit some of the code within this program. I know this is a weird request, but I basically want to do this so that I can allow a C++ program to control the cursor on the screen, this way it is done separately from the Python code.

Right now I have opened my program in Cheat Engine and have found the assembly that writes to the cursor position and I can nop this to make the normal python code that updates the cursor position not work, and then I can write to the cursor's address position and update the cursor manually from cheat engine. However, I am having some difficulty putting this into C++ code.

Every time the application starts, the address of the assembly changes, but the address for the code I want to change has the same offset, so I'm thinking that there is a way to get the pointer to this, but I can't seem to figure out how. Every time the assembly is at 0x00YY0000 + 2DDA, but I can't seem to find a pointer containing 0x00YY0000 and I have no idea on how to obtain this address from C++ using windows handles.

I can provide the program I am trying to hack if you think it would be beneficial along with the C++ code I have written to try and change the memory of said program.

Comment: I have solved my problem by simply searching the memory for the assembly that I wanted to replace, which takes a little longer to load up, but it's not that bad once I get an address I know I can work with it.

Comment: Your question has no question.  What is it that you are trying to find out?